# How can I create the following using Jquery?

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery

I was wonder how can I create something like the image below using jquery? There is a grid with 30 minutes increment that allows the user to click on one segment and they are displayed with three options, online, away and closed. once selected, that information is sent to the server side using json.

I'm just starting to use jquery and don't know where to begine or what to search on google to get started.

Comment: Have you started putting anything together yet?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I'm very new to jquery and I don't even know where to begin or google

Comment: your foundation will be basic html. in this case tabular layout makes sense. First recreate this grid in appearance, then worry about the javascript

Comment: image is no substitute for doing some web searching for dragging table rows and creating a starting mockup with html and basic css

Comment: Thanks I will do that but I'm simply asking for a direction as to where to begin on the jquery stuff. I didn't know that stackoverflow was only for experts (hence the negative points)

Comment: @charlietfl yes thank you, I know how to make simple tables with HTML and CSS, I'm asking help with the jquery portion. If you notice the tags, all I have there is jquery not HTML or CSS

Comment: unfortunately that is irrelevant s you can see from question being closed. Not hard to search regarding drag and drop and have a framework started before asking questions. Even with a basic demo you will get help from community here. Look at jQueryUI draggable as a start  http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Experts?  Definitely not :).  We're all just at some point in our learning career!  That said, stack overflow is for constructive criticism and answers for problems for specific code.  It definitely is not for full tutorials.  Work on it some and post when you get stuck.  We'll gladly help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a matrix where the rows are time and the columns the days of the week.

Then I would create an object with four states online, offline, away, closed which would occupy each one of the positions in the matrix. The stated of each element would change based on the interaction between the user and the UI (meaning those buttons)

You can easily send the json information of each element via ajax to the server by compressing it upon status change.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for actually start me off the right direction. And not criticizing the fact that I'm just starting jquery and was just stumped on where to begine

Comment: "right direction" is a matter of opinion. Your being bombarded with criticism was because your question was a fair equivalent to something like "I like corvettes. How do I build one?"

Comment: Go ahead and try it on your own. Good luck!